# sub-navigation list hidding behind the div

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, z-index

I have got issue with sub navigation list hiding behind the main `div`. I have used `z-index`. I know the problem is because of following block, tried different things but couldn't resolve it.. I am creating dynamic web design and what I want is the width of `.contact_No_01` fill rest of right space, that is why I am using `contact_No_01`.

To refer code: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/toxic_kz/5DrtL/)

```
#header_block2 {
margin:0 auto;
width:90%;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:aqua;
}

#contact_strip {
position:absolute;
width:5%;
right:0;
height:62px;
top:50px;
z-index: 1;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:green; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove `overflow:hidden;` from this CSS and set it to visible:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/5DrtL/3/) (*hover service menu*)

```
#header_block2 {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 90%;
position: relative;
overflow: visible;     /* change is here  */
background-color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: if i remove overflow:hidden, it remove whole block...including nav menu in it